# Problem displaying the stock progress bar on the product pages of my eshop (wordpress & woocommerce)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, progress-bar, stock, inventory

On my eshop capriceparis.fr (managed with wordpress and woocomerce) I would like to display the status of stocks on my product pages visible to users when there are only a few pieces left in stock.

In the woocommerce settings, I selected in "products", "inventory": "display the stock when it is low, more than 2 pieces in stock" but on my product pages nothing happens, no stock progress bar appears.

So I went in "appearance", "customize" because there is a new function in the product pages: "stock progress bar". There it works, the bar appears but it displays the stock of all the products, including when there are 50 pieces in stock.

How to make the stock bar appear only when there are only 2 products left in stock? The problem is not due to javascript or css optimization because I disabled all optimization software. Whether the 2 settings are activated at the same time or not does not change anything.

If someone has encountered the same problem or has a solution, I thank them in advance for their help!